# Diffusion capacitance approximation for bipolar power transistor

Tags: transistors, capacitance

I'm trying to remember the approximation for the value of the diffusion capacitance for a bipolar power transistor.  I think it might have been gm/Ft?  Can anyone confirm this and/or give a reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good old Sedra and Smith fourth edition, pg 322 has the formula as \$C_{de} = \mathrm{T}_{f}*g_m\$ and has a note that \$\mathrm{T}_f\$ is usually in the 10 to 100 picosecond range.  It looks like your formula is equivalent.

Comment: Right-click the formula and select "show source" from the MathJax context menu :- \$C_{DE}=\tau_F.g_m\$

Comment: @Mike, I didn't know you could do that! Nice...